# Should a global object be accessed by a function directly or passed through the function argument?

Tags: python, object, scope

Which of the versions below should be used in Python?

This where the global object `mylist` is accessed directly:

```
def foo1():
    mylist.append(1)
  
def foo2():
    mylist.append(2)
    
mylist = [0]

foo1()
foo2()

print(mylist)
```

or this where the global object `mylist` is passed to the function argument:

```
def foo1(x):
    x.append(1)
  
def foo2(x):
    x.append(2)
    
mylist = [0]

foo1(mylist)
foo2(mylist)

print(mylist)
```

Both return the same output:

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

What is the difference between the two and which version should I use?

Edit:
Giving some real-world context: `mylist` in my project is a `turtle.Turtle()` instance and `foo1` and `foo2` are two functions that each draw something on the same turtle instance.

Comment: You should be asking first why you're using a global variable. The question you've asked here is  opinion based

Comment: @Sayse mylist is in reality a turtle.Turtle() instance and the two functions draw on that instance.

Comment: I would regard `mylist` as not global but as local to the "main" driver of your program (ideally this driver would be in a separate module of its own, and `mylist` would be inaccessible to the core functionality of your program). Then pass it as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's up to you.

The real answer here however is that myList *probably* doesn't need to be global. It should be local, which should then be passed into the functions.

If it's a class variable, you can do either. I would do whichever one does the best job of documenting itself.